# Building R Docker Container with Rocker Scripts on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: r, docker, shiny, shiny-server

I'm having problems with a package that may be solved by rolling back to bionic. With the new modular rocker system it seems like the following would work based on [their build](https://github.com/rocker-org/rocker-versioned2/blob/master/dockerfiles/Dockerfile_r-ver_4.0.0-ubuntu18.04) on 18.04. When I build this with a hello world shiny app I just get shiny_server exited with code 0.

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

# R Ver Env
ENV UBUNTU_VERSION=bionic
ENV R_VERSION=4.0.5
ENV TERM=xterm
ENV LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANG=en_US.UTF-8
ENV R_HOME=/usr/local/lib/R
ENV CRAN=https://packagemanager.rstudio.com/all/__linux__/bionic/latest
ENV TZ=Etc/UTC
# Shiny Env
ENV S6_VERSION=v1.21.7.0
ENV SHINY_SERVER_VERSION=latest
ENV PANDOC_VERSION=default


COPY --from=rocker/r-ver:4.0.5 /rocker_scripts /rocker_scripts

RUN  /rocker_scripts/install_R.sh \
  /rocker_scripts/install_shiny_server.sh \
  /rocker_scripts/install_tidyverse.sh 

EXPOSE 3838


CMD ["/init"]
```

Comment: Where is the code or reference to your shiny app? What's in your `init` script?

Comment: For convenience I'm using a compose script to bring it up. It is mounted in ```/srv/shiny-server/test```. With a normal deployment I assume ```init``` brings up shiny server and shiny server serves anything in the ```/srv/shiny-server``` folder.

Comment: This starts from a plain Ubuntu container (as opposed to a Rocker-with-Ubuntu container) and then tosses in RSPM via just one line (does that work?).  Why not start by customizing the [rocker/r-rspm:18.04](https://github.com/rocker-org/rocker/blob/master/r-rspm/bionic/Dockerfile) container I prepared?

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I hadn't seen the container you prepared, I'll give that a try. I was working through the instructions and examples on the [rocker-versioned2](https://github.com/rocker-org/rocker-versioned2) repository which I thought was the recommended current practice.

Comment: In that case you may want to start from the r-versioned2 containers.  Anyway, background about which stack does what is in our R Journal paper, a lot of discussion is tucked away at GitHub in the different issue ticket discussions which are, sadly, a little split over repos but we try now to transfer them as they arise.

Comment: Yeah I basically started with the dockerfile of [r-ver built on 18.04](https://github.com/rocker-org/rocker-versioned2/blob/master/dockerfiles/Dockerfile_r-ver_4.0.0-ubuntu18.04) and then added exactly what was in the [shiny](https://github.com/rocker-org/rocker-versioned2/blob/master/dockerfiles/Dockerfile_shiny_4.0.5) and [shiny-verse](https://github.com/rocker-org/rocker-versioned2/blob/master/dockerfiles/Dockerfile_shiny-verse_4.0.5) files so I am just wondering why it didn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know why but separating the install scripts into separate layers makes an image that works.

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

# R Ver Env
ENV UBUNTU_VERSION=bionic
ENV R_VERSION=4.0.5
ENV TERM=xterm
ENV LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANG=en_US.UTF-8
ENV R_HOME=/usr/local/lib/R
ENV CRAN=https://packagemanager.rstudio.com/all/__linux__/bionic/291
ENV TZ=Etc/UTC

COPY --from=rocker/r-ver:4.0.5 /rocker_scripts /rocker_scripts

RUN  /rocker_scripts/install_R.sh

# Shiny Env
ENV S6_VERSION=v1.21.7.0
ENV SHINY_SERVER_VERSION=latest
ENV PANDOC_VERSION=default

RUN  /rocker_scripts/install_shiny_server.sh 

RUN /rocker_scripts/install_tidyverse.sh 

EXPOSE 3838

CMD ["/init"]
```

Comment: About the reason: possibly, this might have to do with variables. AFAIK, globally defined env variables are kept but variables created during the creation of the layer "RUN  /rocker_scripts/install_shiny_server.sh" will not be transferred to the execution environment of the next layer creation.